# What is meant by "cut off on the opposite sides" in the following verse of the Quran?

Tags: quran

> The recompense of those who wage war against Allâh and His Messenger and do mischief in the land is only that they shall be killed or crucified or their hands and their feet be cut off on the opposite sides, or be exiled from the land. That is their disgrace in this world, and a great torment is theirs in the Hereafter. [5:33]

Answer (score 1):

It means that both a hand and a foot are to be cut off, and that the hand and the foot that are cut off have to be on different sides of the body, i.e. you can't cut off left hand and left foot, or right hand and right foot.